# What caused the spam warning for this question?

Tags: support, spam

In Triage, I came across this:

[image]

Notice the spam warning:

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully.

[The review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/10461847) has nothing spammy about it at all.

I [asked for any suggestions in the SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27346408#27346408), and nobody seems to have any idea to what caused the warning to show ([not even Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27346424#27346424))

What caused the spam warning?

Comment: The fact that the algorithm isn't 100% accurate in identifying spam is precisely why it's showing the post to a human, rather than just automatically deleting it.  You shouldn't just be assuming that because the algorithm identified it as possible spam that it must be right or something is wrong.  Such is the nature of heuristics.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A few minutes later, [Jon Clements posted this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27346502#27346502) in the SOCVR chat:

> Ahhh - not quite... but looking further - it looks like that account is posting from a network that has had spam posted from it... so that'd be why

So it appears the account is posting from a network known to be a source of spam.

Comment: Spammers needs to find help on SO too

Comment: Hey maybe it's actually spam bot seeking help in order to improve itself.

Comment: @TomášZato https://xkcd.com/810/    mission accomplished?

Comment: OP could have been using a free VPN plugin for his browser. Many people misuse those for spamming and hence systems detect any traffic from it as such. For examples, sometimes Google asks me to fill captcha if I have Browsec or ZenMate extensions on on my chrome. They cite the same reason that previously spam has been detected from this network.